# How to get db file path in java Script Cordova app

Tags: sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have an application which is developed in cordova latest version.I am using sqlite database and I want to copy the db file to internal sdcard of mobile device.How can i get the db file path in javaScript (I don't want to give static path 'data/data//databases').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install this plugin from below link.

https://github.com/jamirooo/DatabasePath-cordova

And try below javascript code. It will give you database path.

```
getDatabasePath: function (callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err){
        alert(err);
    }, "DatabasePath", "getDatabasePath", []);
}
```

Comment: I tried this plugin just now and it is showing some error in the code.( it is showing error in this js code line 1). can you please explain a little bit. it will be helpful.thanx

Comment: have you added this js file in your project ?

Comment: I have added the complete plugin with js file in my project.But showing error.how can i use this properly can you tell.

Comment: also add js file path in your index.html page. like using <script src="path"></script>.

Comment: Thankyou, I am able to resolve the problem.I was not calling the js code properly.